# Outlook Email Template - Send Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook

I am looking to send a saved email template to a user using Python.

This is my current Python function using Win32 library.

How can I adjust this to pick up the template and then send it?

```
def send_email(sender,recipient):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = Subject_Req
    mail.HTMLBody = Content_Email
    mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = sender
    mail.GetInspector 
    mail.Send()
```

I am not able to find the corresponding property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CreateItemFromTemplate.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitemfromtemplate

```
def send_email(sender,recipient):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("pathToTemplate", )
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = Subject_Req
    mail.HTMLBody = Content_Email
    mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = sender
    mail.GetInspector 
    mail.Send()
```